# How to build a WCF Service that returns data in batches

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am trying to build a WCF Service that takes in request records and returns a string response for these records. I am accepting an array of request records. In this array, some records are quickly processed ("fast records") while others take time ("slow records"). So, instead of waiting for all the records to be processed, is it possible to return the fast records first and then send the slow records later on ? The client would update the fast records in the screen immediately and update the slow records as it comes through.

How can I do this with a WCF Service ?

Comment: Two methods: `GetFastRecords` & `GetSlowRecords`

Comment: Maybe a duplex service, if the client is implemented in .NET as well. Or polling, with the method returning the "fast records" immediately and another method which the client calls on intervals, until it has all the "slow records".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can have duplex support I would do it through callbacks.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyServiceCallback
{        
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]        
    void OnRecordResult(string result);
}

[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IMyServiceCallback))]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void GetRecords(string parameter);
}

public class MyService: IMyService
{
    public void GetRecords(string parameter)
    {
        var callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMyServiceCallback>();

        using(var resultCollection = ProcessRecords(parameter))
        {
            foreach(var record in resultCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
                //Transmit the results back to the client as they get put in to resultCollection.
                callback.OnRecordResult(record);
            }
        }

        //We return null as a signal that we are done reporting results, you could also add a 2nd method to the callback to represent being done.
        callback.RecordResult(null);
    }

    private static BlockingCollection<string> ProcessRecords(string parameter)
    {
         var collection = new BlockingCollection<string>();

         //We populate the blocking collection in a background thread.
         Task.Run(() => StartProcessingRecords(parameter, collection);

         return collection;
    }

    private static void StartProcessingRecords(string parameter, BlockingCollection<string> collection)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

---

Here is how you could use it in the client

```
public class MyServiceClient : DuplexClientBase<IMyService>
{
    public MyServiceClient(object callbackInstance, Binding binding, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
        : base(callbackInstance, binding, remoteAddress) { }
}

public class MyServiceCallbackClient : IMyServiceCallback
{
    public event EventHandler<string> RecordResult; //If you are not using .net 4.5 you will need a custom class.

    void IMyServiceCallback.OnRecordResult(string result)
    {
       var tmp = RecordResult;
       if(tmp != null)
           tmp(this, result);
    }
}

IEnumerable<string> GetRecords(string parameter)
{
    var uri = //...
    var binding = //...

    using(var collection = new BlockingCollection<string>())
    {
        var callback = new MyCallbackClient();
        callback.RecordResult += (o, result) =>
        {
             if(result != null)
                 collection.Add(result);
             else
                 collection.CompleteAdding(); //when we get a null we mark the collection complete
        }


        var client = new MyServiceClient(callback, binding, new EndpointAddress(uri));
        var proxy = client.ChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
        proxy.GetRecords();

        foreach(var record in collection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            yield return record;
        }

        client.Close();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, you have to implement `Websocket` in WCF for full fill your requirement.
You can see more detail on http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/341413/What-s-new-in-WCF-4-5-WebSocket-support-Part-2-of